# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'data_siswa' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I have below error when i execute the following script;

```
private void tambahsiswa()
    {
        koneksi.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into data_siswa (nis,nama,kelas,ttl,jenkel,agama,alamat) values ('" + tNis.Text + "','" + tNama.Text + "','" + tKelas.Text + "','" + tTtl.Text + "','" + tJenkel.Text + "','" + tAgama.Text + "','" + rtAlamat.Text + "')", koneksi);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Siswa Telah Di Tambahkan", "Informasi",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
```

Comment: **SQL Injection Alert!** See http://bobby-tables.com Other than that, have you tried debugging? What errors are you seeing? Not much help without any of that...

Comment: One of the columns is created as an identity column. You must either remove this column from the insert statement or change the column to an ordinary (non-identity) column.

Comment: check the indexes on the table data_siswa - you will find a primary key.  you cannot insert into that primary key column unless you issue a command at the beginning of your insert script that goes like this `set identity_insert data_siswa ON`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because you are trying to insert value into the primary key of the table.

If you have a sequence defined for the auto updation of primary key and is linked to the table, you don't mention the identity column in the insert query.

Alternatively you can turn on the identity_insert parameter using a stored procedure.

```
... 
SET IDENTITY_INSERT data_siswa ON
* Your insert query * 
SET IDENTITY_INSERT data_siswa OFF 
...
```